# RecyclerView whole view animation when adding viewitem

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I faced a problem recently, as we know when we add a item to recycle view, we can set item animation when add,update or remove.

The item animation has two steps, it's separated.

1. Move old view items.
2. Start add item animation.

So question is, I need the whole recycle view execute the item animation or merge these two steps to  one step, such as the new added item and old view item move up together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation is automated and combine both of yours. You have to add the new item and call the notifyInsertItem method and after that the scrollToPosition method. 
The animation should work fine

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned after I call scrollToPosition the animation will work, but the animation was not smooth enough, because the old view items will move first then execute the new view item animation.

Comment: Do you make it in this order: 
`adapterList.add(position, newItemObject);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
cardView.scrollToPosition(position);`

This order works perfectly for me. The animation moves first the old entries and make space for the new item. Then it adds the new item and after that it scrolls to the new one.

Comment: Yes, the same like you decribed.

Comment: Ok, then I don't understand your problem :D

Comment: So just want following:
adapterList.add(position,newItemObject);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
cardView.scrollToPosition(position);.

Then the animation move old item and new item together.
Is that possible?

Comment: Do you want to replace one item or only add a new item to your list? If you want to add a new item, do it like I describe it.

Comment: First, I just want to add a new item to list.

Comment: For example.
My screen could display 10 item, then I add a new item to recyclerview.
now there are 11 item and the last item was hiden, then my expect animation like I drag the recyclerview and move up, then the last item should display.

Is that clear this time?

Comment: yes and it should work perfectly with my solution. I do the same in my app.

Comment: You use the cardview??

Comment: Yes i really dont know why its not working in your case

Comment: I too have the same issues...adding the new row doesn't animate the whole view simultaneously ...instead it creates an empty row and then slides in the card view ...